# How to get the link behind the label using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried it in so many ways, but I only get to the hyperlink/label.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'http://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=12&department=0'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

# the second tr in the table - index starts at 0
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content staff-table'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 3:
        link = cols[2].find('a').get('href')
        #link = cols[2].find('a', href=True)
        #link = cols[2].find('a').attrs['href']
        print(link)
```

Here's the output:

```
/staff/2068

/staff/1183

/staff/24563

/staff/1261

/staff/25535
```

Behind each line printed above, there's a link that I would like to get instead of the label.

Here's where I'm getting it from:
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please specify expected output?

Comment: Hi, @OleksiiTambovtsev! I'm trying to get the url behind each line printed above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are relative urls and you have to convert them into asbolute urls.

##### Script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
base_url='http://www.warrencountyschools.org'
url = 'http://www.warrencountyschools.org/district_staff.aspx?action=search&location=12&department=0'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)

# the second tr in the table - index starts at 0
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'content staff-table'})
rows = table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    if len(cols) >= 3:
        link = cols[2].find('a').get('href')
        abs_link= base_url+link
        #link = cols[2].find('a', href=True)
        #link = cols[2].find('a').attrs['href']
        print(abs_link)
```

##### Output:

```
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2068
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1183 
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24563
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1261 
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25535
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14375
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1184 
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24724
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25949
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25652
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1186
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1188
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14132
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1189
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1768
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1191
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1194
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14130
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14072
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25123
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13776
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25994
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1199
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3404
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14022
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24620
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24546
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1203
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3321
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25479
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14418
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1204
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25332
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1206
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25372
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2988
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1205
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13598
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24947
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25159
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25887
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24931
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25093
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25956
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1212
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14245
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24587
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14389
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/26061
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25451
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1438
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1216
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25154
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14227
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1221
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24687
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24472
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1222
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25874
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1223
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1226
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25529
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1227
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1229
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14277
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25460
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24780
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1231
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24932
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1233
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14248
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13890
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14033
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3108
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25146
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24748
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1236
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25156
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1237
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1239
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3152
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1243
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24946
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/26021
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14377
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1806
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1245
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1246
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3248
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24942
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14399
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25069
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13769
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13768
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25884
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1249
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1250
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14016
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1253
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13741
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24631
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25005
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25712
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13719
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25050
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14129
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2842
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/3240
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1256
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25081
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24753
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24471
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14385
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14131
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25219
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2741
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1260
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1262
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13491
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1263
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13928
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1079
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24506
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1267
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24570
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13983
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25415
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25284
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/13935
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24970
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/1273
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/24606
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/25741
http://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/14249
```

Comment: So much info at the same time, being a beginner here, these obvious stuffs go right above my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood what you're asking correctly, the links like `/staff/2068` ARE the link addresses. They are relative to the address of the page. For example go to:

https://www.warrencountyschools.org/staff/2068